# Invalidating session if session user is different from the currently logged in user

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, httpsession

The project that I'm working on consists a single page which is one of the menu items of a drop-down menu on a web page. My single page uses the authentication mechanism of an outside project. I don't understand the details of how but my guess is it's related with `web.xml`, it consists filters such as authentication, validation and httpservletrequest wrapper.

In other words, when I run my project I see a login screen first. An authentication system -that is defined **outside** of my project- runs and if credentials is OK, I'm redirected to my own project's page. The problem is unless the browser is closed completely, the session never gets invalidated. What I want to find is the user name of the currently logged in user. *(This may or may not be the same as the session user.)* So that I can compare this user with the session user and invalidate the session if they are different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use token system, where you can create the token in your outside project and from that end pass that token in redirect url as query param then at your end validate and parse the token.

The token creation and parsing utility should be in common project so that both end projects can use it.